# Confusion with precedence of shift and arithmetic operators in C

Tags: c

I am new to shift operators in C and I am confused by them.

```
int x = 2, y, z = 4;
y =  x>>2  +  z<<1;   // this gives the output 0
y = (x>>2) + (z<<1);  // this gives the output 8
```

I expected both the outputs to be 8, but the first one gives zero. Why is this happening?

Comment: Due to operator precedence.

Comment: Can you please explain

Comment: Well, you got several answers explaining it, but if it's fixed by adding parentheses, then it seems quite obvious that the order without parentheses isn't the same. To be honest, I don't even remember the precedence of all the operators in C, but it doesn't matter since I just put parentheses where I'm not sure. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
y=x>>2 +  z<<1; //this gives the output 0
```

evaluates as

```
y=( x>>(2 +  z)) << 1;
        ^^^^this performed first i.e 6, next x>>6 which is 0 and then 0<<1 is zero
```

because of operator precedence. See the manual page of [operator](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/operator.7.html); it says `+` has higher precedence than the shift operators.

And this

```
y=(x>>2) + (z<<1);  //this gives the output 8
```

is well defined; `()` has highest precedence.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for helping out

Answer (score 2):

If you see e.g. [this operator precedence table](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) you will see that the `+` operator has higher precedence than the shift operators.

That means the expression `x >> 2 + z << 1` is actually equal to `(x >> (2 + z)) << x`.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [operator precedence table](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) for C, you'll see that the addition operator `+` has higher precedence than the left shift and right shift operators `<<` and `>>`.

So this:

```
y=x>>2 +  z<<1;
```

Is the same as:

```
y = (x >> (2 + z) << 1);
```

You need to add parenthesis as you did to change the order in which subexpressions are evaluated.